# Why Does MCF Channel Grouping ≠ Default Channel Grouping?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the GA API.

This is a standard Goal completions metrics table (top) against an MCF goal report (bottom)

Check this out:

[image]

The total number adds up (12,238), but look how different the breakdown is by channel grouping! I assumed these would be close, but nope!

This the same View, no query filters applied, same date range, just one set of metrics by normal channel grouping above, and another set of metrics by mcf channel grouping below.

Answer (score 2):

The standard reports use "last non-direct interaction" as attribution model (which means that direct is under-reported in favour of campaign traffic), while MFC actually uses "last click" (as it says in the table header), so the conversions are attributed differently to the channels.